# Not able to use useState in the default app function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am very new to React and I was trying to use the useState hook to store a request that returns json data in the form :

```
[{"_id":"622fff9046722bfbaace77d1","Country":"United States","CoronavirusCases":81216268,"Deaths":991038,"Recovered":56282006},{"_id":"622fff9846722bfbaace789f","Country":"United Kingdom","CoronavirusCases":19700952,"Deaths":162873,"Recovered":18378375},{"_id":"622fff9846722bfbaace78a0","Country":"Brazil","CoronavirusCases":29382196,"Deaths":655326,"Recovered":27838793},{"_id":"622fff9846722bfbaace78a4","Country":"France","CoronavirusCases":23532997,"Deaths":140294,"Recovered":15867601},{"_id":"622fff9846722bfbaace78a5","Country":"India","CoronavirusCases":42995560,"Deaths":516005,"Recovered":42441449}]
```

I'm using this functional component to return the data:

```
export const FetchCovidData = () => {

  return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/country-ex')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
}
```

This is my App function which should be trying to store the returned JSON into the array CovidData so that I can use it as the dataset for the graphs made using chartJS (which seem to be working fine with sample data I made up in the same format as the returned JSON data) :

```
export default function App() {
  const [CovidData, setCovidData] = useState([]);

  setCovidData(FetchCovidData());
  console.log(CovidData);
  return (

    <div className="App">
    
    <div className='block1'>
      <h1 className='head'>Covid-19</h1>  
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
    </div>  

    <div className='block2'>
      <div className="bar" style={{width:500}}>
        <BarChart ChartData={ CovidData }/>
      </div>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <div className="pie" style={{width:500}}>
        <PieChart ChartData={ CovidData }/>
      </div>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <div className="doughnut" style={{width:500}}>
        <DoughnutChart ChartData={ CovidData }/>
      </div>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <div className="combined" style={{width:500}}>
        <CombinedChart ChartData={ CovidData }/>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

When I look at the console on the website it tells shows me the link to a react error page titled "Invalid Hook Call Warning" pointing to the line where I'm defining the useState for CovidData. I checked that my react and react-dom were the same version. It also seems that using my hook at the top of the function which should be the right way of doing it. I have looked at other posts addressing the same error as me but I found them very difficult to understand and a lot more complicated compared to my situation. I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you call setCovidData, the component will rerender, and after rerender, it call setCovidData, again and again. So we just setCovidData once when the component render the first time or set when we want to. So that, add a useEffect to do it, it's like componentDidMount.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCovidData(FetchCovidData())
}, [])
```

And the func u can try

```
export const FetchCovidData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/country-ex')
    return response?.data || []
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error)
  }
}
```

Or

```
export const FetchCovidData = async () => {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/country-ex')
      .then(res => {
        if (res?.data) resolve(res?.data || [])
        else reject()
      })
      .catch(err) {
        reject(err)
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: In my original code, I replaced everything between the useState declaration and the return statement and replaced it with the useEffect you provided.  After that, I replaced my function with the first function  you provided and it still results in the exact same invalid hook call error. I tried replacing my function with the second one you provided but there seems to be a typo somewhere that I cannot figure out since fixing it in the IDEs suggested method does not compile. Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the notation you are using.

Comment: Also I think I understand what is going wrong in my useState case and I can understand why useEffect should work but I'm not sure what I've done wrong in my Fetch function or why it needs to be fixed so any pointers on that would also be appreciated

Comment: Yeah, the problem is in the hook call, were u use useEffect with the dependency []? 

Your fetch function may not wrong, I just recommend a pretty way to write the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the dependency []. I made sure to include the second parameter of [] in the code you provided if that is what you are talking about. I also imported useEffect in production mode if that changes anything